# Could not bind to 127.0.0.1:9050: Address already in use. Is Tor already running?

Tags: 16.04, tor

I installed Tor this way:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/tor-browser
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install tor-browser
```

I run today in Terminal this: `$ tor` and I got this error message:

```
Oct 04 19:24:04.461 [notice] Tor v0.2.7.6 (git-605ae665009853bd) running on Linux with Libevent 2.0.21-stable, OpenSSL 1.0.2g and Zlib 1.2.8.
Oct 04 19:24:04.461 [notice] Tor can't help you if you use it wrong! Learn how to be safe at https://www.torproject.org/download/download#warning
Oct 04 19:24:04.517 [notice] Read configuration file "/etc/tor/torrc".
Oct 04 19:24:04.574 [notice] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9050
Oct 04 19:24:04.574 [warn] Could not bind to 127.0.0.1:9050: Address already in use. Is Tor already running?
Oct 04 19:24:04.575 [warn] Failed to parse/validate config: Failed to bind one of the listener ports.
Oct 04 19:24:04.575 [err] Reading config failed--see warnings above.
```

How to fix this?

Answer (score 31):

What works for me:

```
killall tor
```

Comment: You need root access

Answer (score 18):

`netstat` will tell you what's listening on that port. Open a terminal (press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>), and run:

```
sudo netstat -plnt | fgrep 9050
```

It will tell you which program is using that port. For example, on my system, it shows:

```
tcp       0     0 127.0.0.1:9050         0.0.0.0:*              LISTEN     1198/tor
```

At the end, it says that the program listening on that port is `tor`.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. Yes, it says tor is using that port. But I am stuck there by getting the same error message

Comment: You may have installed both `tor-browser` and a second Tor package. Try `sudo service tor stop`, and see if Tor browser works after that.

Answer (score 9):

@David Foerster's answer: `killall tor` did not work for me.
I got the result `tor: no process found.`

**New solution: `sudo killall tor`**

Answer (score 3):

For 20.04 install and run tor-browser the next way:

```
sudo apt install torbrowser-launcher
torbrowser-launcher
```

If you want to use `tor` command, than use systemctl to handle its service:

```
sudo systemctl start tor
sudo systemctl stop tor
systemctl status tor
```

After a `tor` service stopping, you could run it with a `tor` command.

You could also use it as a proxy, but it is [not so easy](https://www.linuxuprising.com/2018/10/how-to-install-and-use-tor-as-proxy-in.html).

Answer (score 1):

restart your device and run again. port will be realse.

Comment: No, the port won't be released