# 18.04 TOR Relay Error "Could not bind to 0.0.0.0:9050: Address already in use. Is Tor already running?"

Tags: 18.04, tor

First off - very much a newbie with Ubuntu. Have been running it on an old computer for about 12 months with a TOR relay running.

Followed multiple how-to's and finally got it working. However, just updated to 18.04 last night and for the life of me I cannot get my relay up and running again. I've Googled everything, ran almost every command I can find and I keep getting the same basic problem.

Previous I ran arm to monitor the relay, but after the upgrade that was gone and so I installed NYX. When I tried to run that it says "Unable to connect to tor. Are you sure it's running?" (no - I have no idea, I assumed it was).

```
$ tor
Aug 30 22:01:00.220 [notice] Tor 0.3.3.9 (git-ca1a436fa8e53a32) running on Linux with Libevent 2.1.8-stable, OpenSSL 1.1.0g, Zlib 1.2.11, Liblzma 5.2.2, and Libzstd 1.3.3.
Aug 30 22:01:00.220 [notice] Tor can't help you if you use it wrong! Learn how to be safe at https://www.torproject.org/download/download#warning
Aug 30 22:01:00.220 [notice] Read configuration file "/etc/tor/torrc".
Aug 30 22:01:00.224 [notice] Based on detected system memory, MaxMemInQueues is set to 2862 MB. You can override this by setting MaxMemInQueues by hand.
Aug 30 22:01:00.225 [notice] Scheduler type KIST has been enabled.
Aug 30 22:01:00.225 [notice] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9050
Aug 30 22:01:00.225 [notice] Opening Control listener on 127.0.0.1:9051
Aug 30 22:01:00.225 [notice] Opening OR listener on 0.0.0.0:9001
Aug 30 22:01:00.225 [notice] Opening Directory listener on 0.0.0.0:9050
Aug 30 22:01:00.225 [warn] Could not bind to 0.0.0.0:9050: Address already in use. Is Tor already running?
Aug 30 22:01:00.225 [notice] Closing partially-constructed Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9050
Aug 30 22:01:00.225 [notice] Closing partially-constructed Control listener on 127.0.0.1:9051
Aug 30 22:01:00.225 [notice] Closing partially-constructed OR listener on 0.0.0.0:9001
Aug 30 22:01:00.225 [warn] Failed to parse/validate config: Failed to bind one of the listener ports.
Aug 30 22:01:00.225 [err] Reading config failed--see warnings above.
```

I figured for whatever reason, it wasn't installed correctly. I followed the install instructions on the TOR Project website and did it again. Same message.

I figured, maybe better to remove it all and start again, so I ran:

```
sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove tor
```

Then ran through the whole install process again. Same result / error.

My torrc file appears to be the original one, as whenever I edit it to check, it had all the original settings I had from my previous relay set up.

Found two other threads here that was almost the same (except different IP address), so I also tried all the solutions suggested, including:

```
killall tor
tor:no process found
```

But no change - I'm not sure if it's actually a TOR issue, an IP address issue, have I somehow now install 4 copies of TOR?

Sidenote - Was able to install TOR Browser and that works fine.

I'm keen to get my relay up and running, so I'd be grateful for any advice offered. TIA

**Tried that suggestion:**

Thanks for the reply, unfortunately I'd already tried this and it appears that tor isn't actually running:

```
ben@ben-OptiPlex-755:~$ ps aux | grep -i tor
ben       2435  0.0  0.2 299360  8828 ?        Ssl  11:27   0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfs-udisks2-volume-monitor
ben       2442  0.0  0.1 371736  7616 ?        Ssl  11:27   0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfs-afc-volume-monitor
ben       2447  0.0  0.1 281680  6616 ?        Ssl  11:27   0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfs-gphoto2-volume-monitor
ben       2454  0.0  0.1 268764  6056 ?        Ssl  11:27   0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfs-mtp-volume-monitor
ben       2458  0.0  0.1 266968  5916 ?        Ssl  11:27   0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfs-goa-volume-monitor
ben       2593  0.0  0.2 464988 10476 tty2     Sl+  11:27   0:00 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/indicator-application/indicator-application-service
ben       2603  0.0  0.2 366280  7828 tty2     Sl+  11:27   0:00 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/indicator-messages/indicator-messages-service
ben       2636  0.0  1.6 884620 66384 ?        Ssl  11:27   0:00 /usr/lib/evolution/evolution-calendar-factory
ben       2704  0.0  1.5 1054588 61800 ?       Sl   11:27   0:00 /usr/lib/evolution/evolution-calendar-factory-subprocess --factory all --bus-name org.gnome.evolution.dataserver.Subprocess.Backend.Calendarx2636x2 --own-path /org/gnome/evolution/dataserver/Subprocess/Backend/Calendar/2636/2
ben       2733  0.0  0.6 725764 24104 ?        Ssl  11:27   0:00 /usr/lib/evolution/evolution-addressbook-factory
ben       2746  0.0  0.6 1075752 26984 ?       Sl   11:27   0:00 /usr/lib/evolution/evolution-addressbook-factory-subprocess --factory all --bus-name org.gnome.evolution.dataserver.Subprocess.Backend.AddressBookx2733x2 --own-path /org/gnome/evolution/dataserver/Subprocess/Backend/AddressBook/2733/2
ben       3786  0.0  0.8 101515084 32172 tty2  Sl+  11:29   0:00 /usr/lib/deja-dup/deja-dup-monitor
ben       4383  0.0  0.0  14428  1088 pts/0    S+   11:40   0:00 grep --color=auto -i tor
```

Or is that very last process 4383 the Tor process? Nope, doesn't appear so as it says no such process when I run

> kill -9 4383

Other suggestions? :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Could not bind to 127.0.0.1:9050: Address already in use. Is Tor already running?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/833021/could-not-bind-to-127-0-0-19050-address-already-in-use-is-tor-already-running)

Answer (score 0):

Can you please get the running tor process, and kill it:

```
ps aux | grep -i tor
```

It will show you the tor process id, Now you can kill it, if it's running:

```
kill -9 process_id
```

Hope this will help you. :)

Comment: Thanks NOrbert for the edit and correcting the sentence syntax.

Comment: Thank you - tried those commands, but didn't fix it. Original posted updated.

Comment: What is the error message, when you are reinstalling tor.

Comment: I don't get an error when it's installing, Tor appears to install fine. But when I run nyx it says "Unable to connect to tor. Are you sure it's running?" Hence the reason I run the Tor command to get that initial message at the top. It appears Tor can't get itself booted up.

Answer (score 0):

OK so the guys over on the Tor-Relay mailing listed solved my issue:
I had too many things trying to access the same ports.
ie SOCKS & Directory Listener were both trying 9050.

Once I changed all the ports to separate ones, it was happy!
ie

- Control Port 9030 - not required to be open on the router.
- DirPort 9051 - open on the router.
- SOCKS 9050 - not open on the router.
- OR Port 9001 - open on the router.

As stated above, I had two trying to get out through the same port - Doh!!

Thanks to the advice offered though :)